# Dynamic configuration and persistent storage for config

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

I have the following two requirements in my NestJS application:

- Dynamic configuration - allow users to change configuration values at runtime and allow for observing changes in configuration and take some action based on it.
- Database storage - Store configuration in persistent store like Redis.

I have been looking into the `@nestjs/config` library but I couldn't find anything regarding this.

I was wondering if anybody has used it for such purpose? In case it doesn't support these features, does the library provide any extension hooks? How easy or difficult would it be to implement it in the library or on top of it? Or it's simply not meant for such usage and I should look elsewhere?

I'm quite competent when it comes to NodeJS and JS/TS ecosystem, so wouldn't mind implementing it myself if I get some clues. Would appreciate any thoughts on it.

Comment: I believe that `@nestjs/config` was not built for that purpose. Anyway, taking what you said as literal as possible, you're looking to update some value and react when you do so. Why not just use a database and access this value whenever needed, and then update it via some API call? It doesn't have to be tied to NestJS's config mechanism.